# How do I mount ejected external USB flash Via terminal

Tags: command-line, usb

After safely remove or eject it, i want to remount it without unplug it, and re-plug it again ..
so Any suggestion pls?

PS

after using eject all usb memories are out of `fdisk` command scope i don't think it is that easy

```
`       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1       109473792  1953525167   922025688   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         2050048    99706297    48828125   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        99708926   109471743     4881409    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5        99708928   109471743     4881408   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order`
```

None of them is the usb memory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check what dev is your usb. It should be in FAT (most common) or NTFS

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

First you have to create mount point.

```
sudo mkdir /media/external
```

If your USB device is /dev/sdb1 and FAT

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/external -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

NTFS

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

For unmount

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

or:

```
sudo umount /media/external
```

I basically told you what is written in the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB).

Comment: after using eject all usb memories are out of fdisk command scope
 i don't think it is that easy

Comment: This works if you use unmount as still the USB is not powered down. Using the `sudo eject -t /dev/sdb` which I supposed from your post that you used, the USB node will be created again and then you can `mount/unmount` as mentioned above. I tried this before and works perfectly fine. I will try again whenever I have access to Linux machine.

Comment: why doen't appear in `fdisk` output then?

Comment: Safely Remove or Eject power down the device and the node in /dev will be destroyed. Using the `eject -t` will trigger it and you will see it again in fdisk. Read more details [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5845/what-is-the-difference-between-unmount-eject-safely-remove-drive-and-the) and try what I suggested.

Comment: Safely Remove or Eject power down how to get it back in this case ?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo eject -t /dev/sdb`? This supposed to trigger the power cycle then mount it.