# How can I mount an ejected USB drive without unplugging it?

Tags: mount, usb-drive, unmount, eject

I am on an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS system. I use `udisksctl` command to mount and unmount my USB flash drive, but I sometimes eject it in nautilus. I can see the device in Disks utility even after ejecting.

I searched the site and found the question [How do I mount ejected external USB flash Via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525221/how-do-i-mount-ejected-external-usb-flash-via-terminal), but I could not find an answer to **mount an ejected USB drive** in the answers of that question.

Can you please explain  to me how to mount an ejected USB drive without unplugging it?

Answer (score 8):

The following will eject the USB device.

```
sudo eject /dev/sde
```

The following will mount the USB device without unplugging it.

```
sudo eject -t /dev/sde
```

Reference: http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/09/how-to-remount-usb-stick-without.html

Answer (score 6):

Check your usb flash name with:

```
lsusb
```

my sandisk example:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0781:540e SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Contour Flash Drive
```

Now i know my sandisk is on bus **003** and device **005**
Then you have to check your usb bus and port number with:

```
lsusb -t
```

> ```
> Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
> |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
> ```

Now i know that bus 3 device 5 is on port **5** so we can go to :

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb
```

and disable port:

```
sudo tee unbind <<< "3-5"
```

or enable port:

```
sudo tee bind <<< "3-5"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but What is [this problem](http://telegra.ph/usb-terminal-12-11)?

Comment: @NuwanThisara its already unbinded. Can you bind it again  and then mount ?

Comment: same message... [image](http://telegra.ph/bind-12-13)

Comment: Not successful. What is the wrong I did?

Comment: There is a work-around. If you unmount a USB drive with *umount* instead of eject, it will not be powered off, and it is available to be mounted again with *mount*.

Answer (score 1):

When I inserted my usb drive I got this:

```bsh
ls /dev/sdd*
```

> /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1

I then ejected it

```bsh
sudo eject /dev/sdd
ls /dev/sdd*
```

> /dev/sdd

I then unejected it as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-to-re-mount-a-usb-stick-after-unmounting-from-nautilus-without-disconnecting)

```bsh
sudo eject -t /dev/sdd
ls /dev/sdd*
```

> /dev/sdd  /dev/sdd1

You might want to check the disk by using fdisk

```bsh
sudo fdisk /dev/sdd -l
```